# How to set the format of a <$view > to wiki in tiddlywiki?

Tags: tiddlywiki

In my tiddler, I have the following field:

- name : my_field
- value : [[Some Page I Want To Link To]]

Then, in the same tiddler, I use the following ViewWidget to see the content of the file:

```
<$view field="my_field" />
```

The problem is that the rendered text is not wikified, and thus, there is no link despite me having wrapped the name with [[ and ]].

How can I do to have my text rendered as a proper link?

Note: Removing the spaces is not an option.

P.S.: Of course, I tried the documentation, that is:

- http://tiddlywiki.com/#ViewWidget
- http://tiddlywiki.com/#LinkWidget

... including changing the format, etc., but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the transclude widget, instead of the view widget:

```
<$transclude field="my_field" />
```

Comment: this worked for me with one drawback: markdown is ignored. E.g., lists of the format `* blabla` are not rendered as lists, but lists of the format `<ul><li>blabla</li></ul>` are rendered as lists. (markdown works fine in the original, non-transcluded tiddler).

Comment: adding `mode=block` solved this problem (see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tiddlywiki/wVbBgHQs5qQ/Mu64zdUPVe8J)

Answer (score 0):

If your field **my_field** has the value: **Some Page I Want To Link To**

Then use:

```
<$link to={{!!my_field}} >{{!!my_field}}
</$link>
```

Comment: Note that this can be abbreviated `<$link to={{!!my_field}}/>` -- the value of `to` will be used for the body if the body is empty.